# Set-Location Powershell provider

Tags: powershell, powershell-provider

I'm having some trouble browsing a powershell I have created.

I have implemented the methods listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The documentation also says

> Set-Location: This cmdlet sets the current working location to a specified location. You do >not need to overwrite any methods to support this cmdlet.

But I'm getting the error

> cd : Provider operation stopped because the provider does not support this operation.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + cd banksia:\
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Set-Location], PSNotSupportedException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

What do I have to implement to make Set-Location work?

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide a chunk of code that generated this error? I can then try to run the code and see if I can help figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you derive from [NavigationCmdletProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management.Automation.Provider.NavigationCmdletProvider%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?  That is required to support Set-Location IIRC.  It relies on the provided implementation of `bool IsItemContainer(string path)`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

I had derived from NavigationCmdletProvider, but not implemented IsItemContainer. The documentation I was reading my be out of date.